# How to check if the element with visibility exists or not cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

Is there any way to check if the element with visibility exists or not

```
cy.get("[data-ta='member_account_switch']:visible")
```

event though there are two elements with same data key exists on the dom but both are not visible I just want to check if the visible element exists or not

```
cy.get("[data-ta='member_account_switch']:visible").should('not.exists')
```

this above statement does not work as ***cy.get("[data-ta='member_account_switch']:visible")*** is trying to find the element.
and I get the below error

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: [data-ta='member_account_switch']:visible, but never found it.
```

can someone help here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong in both the cases. You should write like below. `cy.get()` method takes only locators. In your case the locator is `[data-ta='member_account_switch']` and on top of that you have to check it's property.

```
cy.get("[data-ta='member_account_switch']").should('be.visible')
```

Please read about Cypress and how to use these before posting simple things here.